# Why is repo(use git inside) sometimes slow and unstable?

Tags: git, repo

I'm trying to get a project using `repo,` and I learn that it is actually using git to clone objects inside it.

However, it's just too unstable, sometimes it is up to 1.5M/s and sometimes even slower than 10KB/s, which finally causes an `early EOF` error! I don't think something is wrong with my network as `apt-get` and other repositories work at a normal speed.

To make things worse, it seems that repo is not able to cache the objects it gets(e.g. If I get an `early EOF` error at 92%, I have to repo the whole object again!). That is a waste of time and traffic!

Does anyone know how to solve the problem?
Thanks in advance.
Tgn

Comment: As you're saying it's just running Git commands. If they're slow then Repo is slow. You can run `repo --trace sync` to have it print the exact commands it runs. The comparison to apt-get isn't relevant since they use completely different servers.

Comment: Well, actually I don't know how exactly `repo` works, but it has `git` infomation in it's configure file, which is `.xml` file. It is solved after I switch to a more stable network, so maybe it was a matter of the network. Thanks anyway.